# Duckdb release memory in python

Tags: delta-lake, duckdb

I've started to experiment with duckdb but have struggled to figure out, how we can release memory again. If I have a loop like below, I would have imagined that memory gets either freed after process is over or after con.close() was called. But on my system neither seems to be the case, if I look at the memory used by the process, there is still memory occupied (very likely by duckdb, as this is essentially all I'm doing. Unless deltalake or pyarrow have issues)

```py
import duckdb
import deltalake
for src in ["a","b", "c"]:
        def process():
                con = duckdb.connect(":memory:")
                dt = deltalake.DeltaTable(f"s3a://{src}", storage_options=deltalake_storage_options)
                pa = dt.to_pyarrow_table()
                r1 = con.from_arrow(pa)
                duckdb.sql("select * from r1").write_parquet("/tmp/test.parquet")
        process()
```

As some of the tables I'm dealing with are very large, I cannot keep all of them in memory at the same time. So how would I be able to release all of the memory, that is allocated to duckdb?

Answer (score 0):

You might have luck using

```py
con.from_arrow(pa).write_parquet("/tmp/test.parquet")
```

As that doesn't use the "default" connection, as the methods directly on the module (eg, duckdb.sql) do

Answer (score 0):

Would `con.close()` at the end of `process()` help?

Comment: Unfortuantely not. I think I have the same problem that someone had reported here: https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/issues/9033

Comment: I had a similar issue and managed to get code that emitted a `pyarrow.RecordBatchReader` of smaller `pyarrow` tables that could be written to `parquet` one at a time. This dramatically reduced the memory footprint for me. Perhaps something similar could work for you.

https://gist.github.com/iangow/2d8f7be06fea688ec9b84bc45c6c473a